# Google Data Studio can't count user count for an analytics event

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

So i've an app that logs events to firebase/google analytics for instance lets say the event name is 'log_purchase'

I can use data studio and create a filter but now if i select my metric as
event count i can see a value but if i change it to 'Active Users' as in total number of unique users that triggered this event

It says no data, what am i doing wrong how can i see either active user count or event count that only logs users once

[image: log purchase event]

[image: filter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it needs at least around 40-45 users before the data studio shows them after that it starts to work properly.